# Unable to Track Scans of QR Codes in Backend Web Application

Tags: nestjs, qr-code, tracking

I'm working on a web application that allows users to generate and customize QR codes for various use cases, including Wi-Fi networks, events, and locations. One of the requirements for the application is to track the stats of each QR code when other users scan it.

I'm using NestJS as the backend web service for the application, and I'm struggling to find a way to track the scans of the QR codes in a reliable way. I've considered using server-side analytics tools like Google Analytics, but this approach doesn't seem to be feasible for my use case since I have many different QR code types with different data formats.

One approach I've considered is to generate a unique URL for each QR code that redirects to a server-side endpoint in my web service, which can then be used to record the scan of the QR code and track the relevant data. However, this approach doesn't work well for Wi-Fi QR codes since redirecting the user to a URL won't allow their device to connect to the network.

Another approach I've considered is to include the Wi-Fi network information directly in the QR code itself, instead of using a URL. This way, when a user scans the QR code, their device will be able to automatically connect to the Wi-Fi network without needing to open a URL. However, I'm not sure how to track the scans of these QR codes in a reliable way.

I'm hoping to get some guidance on the best approach to track the scans of my QR codes in my backend web service. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, you have "data" to present to the user. This can be a setup of wifi or other things. But if you embed "data" directly in the code, you have no way of tracking scans, since the scan will be on user device only. If you don't embed data directly but instead make "data" a key on your server, you can force user to go to a url or even scan using a special app. But you lose functionality and potentially users (not everyone will make the effort to use a special app etc).   If you can make your QRs unique, you can use unique passwords on each in mecard format, and track each login.

Comment: I agree with all above. But, what do you mean by "making QRs unique"?